# Fourier series of multiplicative inverse of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

Suppose we know the Fourier series of a function $$f(x) = \sum_k c_k e^{ikx}$$. 
Is there any explicit relation to find the fourier series of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ in terms of the coefficients of the fourier series of $f(x)$? i.e, if the fourier series of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $$\frac{1}{f(x)}= \sum_k d_k e^{ikx}$$can we express $d_k$ in terms of $c_k$'s?

(Assuming $f(x)$ and $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ both exist throughout $\mathbb{R}$ and are smooth.)

Comment: An analogous problem is that of [inverting power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Inverting_series). As you can see in the link, the coefficients of the inverse power series satisfy a recursive formula in terms of the coefficients of the original series. (We say that these are *formal* power series because at this point we still need to check convergence). This is relevant to your problem because the substitution $z=e^{ix}$ turns a Fourier series into a Laurent series, which is a more general concept than a power series because it involves negative powers also.

Comment: You might do a literature search and see if there is a formula for the inverse of a formal Laurent series. At any rate, the formula for the formal power series given in the above Wikipedia link will work if your Fourier series only contains a finite number of negative modes (i.e., if there exists a $K\ge 0$ such that $c_k=0$ for all $k\le  -K$).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Passing over the question of how to extend this to Laurent series, it's not clear to me that this even works for a Fourier series "of power series type", meaning $a_n=0$ for $n<0$. Consider $f=e^{it}-1/2$. The Fourier series for $1/f$ is _not_ of power series type! (Because if it were it would give a function $1/(z-1/2)$ holomorphic in the unit disk.) If you do formally invert the power series in this example you get the power series for $1/f$ in the disk $|z|<1/2$, which has little bearing on the Fourier coefficients of $1/f$ on the unit circle...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I see. I was over optimistic. However, one can at least say that the formal power series method works if $f$ is the restriction to the unit circle of a holomorphic function on a neighborhood of the unit disk $D$ that never vanishes on $\overline D$. That's probably not much but maybe it can be useful.

Comment: It is a bit late but I wonder if this helps: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not much more to say - can't prove there is no such formula, but there isn't.

For example: Recall Wiener's theorem: If $f=\sum a_ne^{int}$, $f$ has no zero on the circle, and $\sum|a_n|<\infty$ then $1/f=\sum b_ne^{int}$, *where* $\sum|b_n|<\infty$. If there were  a formula for $b_n$ in terms of $a_n$ people would prove this, or try to do so, using that formula. It's precisely the non-existence of such a formula that makes the theorem amazing: Somehow we show that $\sum|a_n|<\infty$ implies $\sum|b_n|<\infty$ even though we have no explicit way to get our hands on $b_n$ given $(a_n)$.

Comment: Whoever voted to delete this: Suppose for the sake of argument that there is in fact no such formula. What would a better answer to the question look like?

Comment: +1: this is quite convincing. Of course it is impossible to prove that a formula "does not exist". Your argument is convincing. BTW, I was not the delete voter. (I also find the close vote to the original question inappropriate and unfriendly towards a new user).

Answer (score 0):

See Theorem 4 of the article "The Reciprocal of a Fourier Series" by R.J. Duffin. I'll reproduce the gist here.

Suppose $F(x), 1/F(x) \in L^2([0,1])$ and $F(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_j e^{2\pi i j x}$. Define
$$g_j =\sum_{-\infty}^\infty f_{j+r} f_r^*.$$

The equations

$$f_{-j}^* = \sum_{-m}^m g_{j-k} \alpha_k$$

may be solved for $\alpha_{-m},\ldots, \alpha_m$. Then as $m\to \infty$, $\sum_{-m}^m \alpha_m e^{2\pi im x}$ converges to $1/F(x)$.